# Segmentation fault on parallelization with OpenMP

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp

I am using OpenMP to parallel the following function

```
float myfunc ( Class1 *class1, int *feas, int numfeas, float z, long *k, double cost, long iter, float e )
{
    long i;
    long x;
    double sum;

    sum = cost;
    while ( change/cost > 1.0*e ) {
        change = 0.0;

        intshuffle ( feas, numfeas );

        #pragma omp parallel for private (i,x) firstprivate(z,k) reduction (+:sum)
        for ( i=0; i<iter; i++ ) {
            x = i%numfeas;
            sum += pgain ( feas[x], class1, z, k );
        }
        cost -= sum;
    }
    return ( cost );
}
```

This returns a "**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**" error

When I change my pragma to

```
#pragma omp parallel for private (i,x) firstprivate(class1,feas,z,k) reduction (+:sum)`
```

I get a "**double free or corruption (out): 0xb6a00468**" error.

From my limited knowledge of OpenMp i understand this is due to faulty memory access to pointers concerning **class1** and **feas**.

For reference I post also my Class1 code

```
typedef struct {
    float w;
    float *c;
    long a;  
    float co;  
} Class1;
```

Please advice on the proper way to parallelise the above function.

**Update:**

The pgain function

```
double pgain ( long x, Class1 *class1, double z, long int *numcenters )
{
    int i;
    int number_of_centers_to_close = 0;

    static double *work_mem;
    static double gl_cost_of_opening_x;
    static int gl_number_of_centers_to_close;

    int stride = *numcenters + 2;
    //make stride a multiple of CACHE_LINE
    int cl = CACHE_LINE/sizeof ( double );
    if ( stride % cl != 0 ) {
        stride = cl * ( stride / cl + 1 );
    }
    int K = stride - 2 ; // K==*numcenters

    //my own cost of opening x
    double cost_of_opening_x = 0;

    work_mem = ( double* ) malloc ( 2 * stride * sizeof ( double ) );
    gl_cost_of_opening_x = 0;
    gl_number_of_centers_to_close = 0;

    /*
     * For each center, we have a *lower* field that indicates
     * how much we will save by closing the center.
     */
    int count = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < class1->num; i++ ) {
        if ( is_center[i] ) {
            center_table[i] = count++;
        }
    }
    work_mem[0] = 0;

    //now we finish building the table. clear the working memory.
    memset ( switch_membership, 0, class1->num * sizeof ( bool ) );
    memset ( work_mem, 0, stride*sizeof ( double ) );
    memset ( work_mem+stride,0,stride*sizeof ( double ) );

    //my *lower* fields
    double* lower = &work_mem[0];
    //global *lower* fields
    double* gl_lower = &work_mem[stride];

    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for ( i = 0; i < class1->num; i++ ) {
        float x_cost = dist ( class1->p[i], class1->p[x], class1->dim ) * class1->p[i].weight;
        float current_cost = class1->p[i].cost;

        if ( x_cost < current_cost ) {

            // point i would save cost just by switching to x
            // (note that i cannot be a median,
            // or else dist(p[i], p[x]) would be 0)

            switch_membership[i] = 1;
            cost_of_opening_x += x_cost - current_cost;

        } else {

            // cost of assigning i to x is at least current assignment cost of i

            // consider the savings that i's **current** median would realize
            // if we reassigned that median and all its members to x;
            // note we've already accounted for the fact that the median
            // would save z by closing; now we have to subtract from the savings
            // the extra cost of reassigning that median and its members
            int assign = class1->p[i].assign;
            lower[center_table[assign]] += current_cost - x_cost;
        }
    }

    // at this time, we can calculate the cost of opening a center
    // at x; if it is negative, we'll go through with opening it

    for ( int i = 0; i < class1->num; i++ ) {
        if ( is_center[i] ) {
            double low = z + work_mem[center_table[i]];
            gl_lower[center_table[i]] = low;
            if ( low > 0 ) {
                // i is a median, and
                // if we were to open x (which we still may not) we'd close i

                // note, we'll ignore the following quantity unless we do open x
                ++number_of_centers_to_close;
                cost_of_opening_x -= low;
            }
        }
    }
    //use the rest of working memory to store the following
    work_mem[K] = number_of_centers_to_close;
    work_mem[K+1] = cost_of_opening_x;

    gl_number_of_centers_to_close = ( int ) work_mem[K];
    gl_cost_of_opening_x = z + work_mem[K+1];

    // Now, check whether opening x would save cost; if so, do it, and
    // otherwise do nothing

    if ( gl_cost_of_opening_x < 0 ) {
        //  we'd save money by opening x; we'll do it
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for ( int i = 0; i < class1->num; i++ ) {
            bool close_center = gl_lower[center_table[class1->p[i].assign]] > 0 ;
            if ( switch_membership[i] || close_center ) {
                // Either i's median (which may be i itself) is closing,
                // or i is closer to x than to its current median
                #pragma omp critical
                {
                class1->p[i].cost = class1->p[i].weight * dist ( class1->p[i], class1->p[x], class1->dim );
                class1->p[i].assign = x;
                }
            }
        }
        for ( int i = 0; i < class1->num; i++ ) {
            if ( is_center[i] && gl_lower[center_table[i]] > 0 ) {
                is_center[i] = false;
            }
        }
        if ( x >= 0 && x < class1->num ) {
            is_center[x] = true;
        }

        *numcenters = *numcenters + 1 - gl_number_of_centers_to_close;
    } else {
        gl_cost_of_opening_x = 0;  // the value we'll return
    }

    free ( work_mem );

    return -gl_cost_of_opening_x;
}
```

**Update 2**

Fixed pgain cause on my version i have #pragma directives also in pgain

And here is a stack trace

```
#0  0xb7d50750 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0xb7eaa198 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1
#2  0x080493a0 in pgain (x=2982, class1=0xbffff218, z=1461.919921875, 
    numce=0x804d128) at streamcluster-openmp.cpp:232
#3  0x0804aaf6 in myfunc(Class1*, int*, int, float, long*, double, long, float) [clone ._omp_fn.0] () at openmp.cpp:347
#4  0xb7ea9889 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1
#5  0xb7cbcd4c in start_thread () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#6  0xb7dc9bae in clone () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Comment: Are you sure that `i` has to be private? I'm pretty sure you can leave out that directive, and inline `x`. I need to look back at my OpenMP notes...

Comment: @Mysticial pgain is another function the signature is double pgain ( long x, Class1 *class1, double z, long int *numcent ). But it doesnt matter cause the code compiles and runs correctly without the OpenMP pragmas

Comment: @millinon i doesnt need to be private cause OpenMp is smart enough to recognise it as private but x need to be private declared. The problem is with shared memory probably and the ponters of feas and class1.

Comment: Are you by any chance allocating memory inside that function? Is the memory allocator thread-safe?

Comment: @Mysticial yes i am running a malloc inside pgain

Comment: That's why I asked - you have i marked as private. If x is just i%numfeas, you don't even need to use x - just use `feas[i % numfeas]` in the function call. That being said, that probably doesn't have anything to do with your memory error, so we're going to need to see `pgain`'s definition.

Comment: Your last update introduced a lot of data races. I would suggest to review the semnatic of OpenMP `critical` and `parallel` constructs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may be a possible race-condition in this part of `pgain`:

```
// Either i's median (which may be i itself) is closing,
// or i is closer to x than to its current median
class1->p[i].cost = class1->p[i].weight * dist ( class1->p[i], class1->p[x], class1->dim );
class1->p[i].assign = x;
```

As `class1` is a pointer, what you make private with the statement `firstprivate(class1)` is the bare pointer, not the underlying resource.

The solution to this issue highly depends on the semantic of your program. If it is fine to have randomly ordered updates of `*class1`, and the resource is really meant to be shared, then the following modification:

```
// Either i's median (which may be i itself) is closing,
// or i is closer to x than to its current median
#pragma omp critical LOCK_CLASS1
{
  // Lock this part of the code for thread-safety
  class1->p[i].cost = class1->p[i].weight * dist ( class1->p[i], class1->p[x], class1->dim );
  class1->p[i].assign = x
}
```

will fix the code above. Otherwise you should create private copies of `*class1` for each thread before calling `pgain`.

Finally, you should note that the above reasoning remains true for **any resource**. For instance, the pointer `float *c` in `Class1` shows the same critical point if it refers to a resource that is shared and you don't synchronize memory updates.

Comment: So what is your suggested solution to the problem of parellization?

Comment: Couldn’t fix it. I have update my original post with new info.

Comment: I am accepting as answer your post. It was indeed he race conditions that caused the seg faults.